# wmi code leaking

Tags: c++

I have copied and modified a piece of code from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Its leaking memory. please help.

```
#include "querysink.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
HRESULT hres;
hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    return 1;                  // Program has failed.
}



hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
    NULL, 
    -1,                          // COM authentication
    NULL,                        // Authentication services
    NULL,                        // Reserved
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
    RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
    NULL,                        // Authentication info
    EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
    NULL                         // Reserved
    );


if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;                    // Program has failed.
}



IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;

hres = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WbemLocator,             
    0, 
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
    IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object."
        << " Err code = 0x"
        << hex << hres << endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;                 // Program has failed.
}


IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;


hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
    _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), 
    NULL,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    0,
    0, 
    &pSvc
    );

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
         << hex << hres << endl;
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;                // Program has failed.
}

cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;




hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
   pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
   RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
   RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
   NULL,                        // Server principal name 
   RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
   RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
   NULL,                        // client identity
   EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}


QuerySink* pResponseSink = new QuerySink();
hres = pSvc->ExecQueryAsync(
    bstr_t("WQL"), 
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent"),
    WBEM_FLAG_BIDIRECTIONAL, 
    NULL,
    pResponseSink);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Query for log collection failed."
        << " Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pResponseSink->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}


while(pResponseSink->IsDone()==false){
        Sleep(100);
        }


pSvc->Release();
pLoc->Release();
CoUninitialize();
while(1)
{
 //do other job here
}


return 0;   // Program successfully completed.

}//end of file
```

//querysink.cpp

```
#include "querysink.h"

ULONG QuerySink::AddRef()
{
return InterlockedIncrement(&m_lRef);
}

ULONG QuerySink::Release()
{
LONG lRef = InterlockedDecrement(&m_lRef);
if(lRef == 0)
    delete this;
return lRef;
}

HRESULT QuerySink::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv)
{
if (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == IID_IWbemObjectSink)
{
    *ppv = (IWbemObjectSink *) this;
    AddRef();
    return WBEM_S_NO_ERROR;
}
else return E_NOINTERFACE;
}


HRESULT QuerySink::Indicate(long lObjectCount,
IWbemClassObject **apObjArray)
{
HRESULT hres = S_OK;
VARIANT writtenTime,genTime,logFile,eventCode,eventId,eventType,category;

for (int i = 0; i < lObjectCount; i++)
{
            hres = apObjArray[i]->Get(L"TimeWritten", 0, &writtenTime, 0, 0);
            hres = apObjArray[i]->Get(L"TimeGenerated", 0, &genTime, 0, 0);
            hres = apObjArray[i]->Get(L"Logfile", 0, &logFile, 0, 0);
            hres = apObjArray[i]->Get(L"Category", 0, &category, 0, 0);
            hres = apObjArray[i]->Get(L"EventCode", 0, &eventCode, 0, 0);
            hres = apObjArray[i]->Get(L"EventIdentifier", 0, &eventId, 0, 0);
            hres = apObjArray[i]->Get(L"EventType", 0, &eventType, 0, 0);
```

//if i remove above 7 lines then memory consumption is just fine.

```
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to get the data from the query"
            << " Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        return WBEM_E_FAILED;       // Program has failed.
    }


}
VariantClear(&writtenTime);
VariantClear(&genTime);
VariantClear(&category);
VariantClear(&eventCode);
VariantClear(&eventId);
VariantClear(&eventType);
VariantClear(&logFile);

return WBEM_S_NO_ERROR;
}

HRESULT QuerySink::SetStatus(
        /* [in] */ LONG lFlags,
        /* [in] */ HRESULT hResult,
        /* [in] */ BSTR strParam,
        /* [in] */ IWbemClassObject __RPC_FAR *pObjParam
    )
{
if(lFlags == WBEM_STATUS_COMPLETE)
{
    printf("Call complete.\n");

    EnterCriticalSection(&threadLock);
    bDone = true;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&threadLock);
}
else if(lFlags == WBEM_STATUS_PROGRESS)
{
    printf("Call in progress.\n");
}

return WBEM_S_NO_ERROR;
}


bool QuerySink::IsDone()
{
bool done = true;

//  EnterCriticalSection(&threadLock);
done = bDone;
//  LeaveCriticalSection(&threadLock);

return done;
}    // end of querysink.cpp
```

//querysink.h

```
#ifndef QUERYSINK_H
#define QUERYSINK_H

#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

# pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

class QuerySink : public IWbemObjectSink
{
LONG m_lRef;
bool bDone;
CRITICAL_SECTION threadLock; // for thread safety

public:
QuerySink() { m_lRef = 0; bDone = false; 
    InitializeCriticalSection(&threadLock); }
~QuerySink() { bDone = true;
    DeleteCriticalSection(&threadLock); }

virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef();
virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release();        
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid,
    void** ppv);

virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Indicate( 
        LONG lObjectCount,
        IWbemClassObject __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *apObjArray
        );

virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetStatus( 
        /* [in] */ LONG lFlags,
        /* [in] */ HRESULT hResult,
        /* [in] */ BSTR strParam,
        /* [in] */ IWbemClassObject __RPC_FAR *pObjParam
        );

bool IsDone();
};

#endif    // end of querysink.h
```

Comment: How do you know it is leaking? What conditions did you observe for the leak to happen? Do you know when it happens? How large is the leak? How often does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for [IWebmServices::Get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa391442%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also your variant clearence is wrong, you are basically abusing its usage, consider moving the decleration and freeing of your variants inside the for loop. Your are getting the variants by reference and after you're done with each one you should clear it before getting the property of the next object in the `apObjArray` as you'll be getting a  different object. What your code does is only free the last reference fetched of each variant. Also since you are using the same `HRESULT` object for all your `Get` calls this would mean that if any call fails you'll not free the properties and that would cause a leak.

Consider replacing your code with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lObjectCount; i++)
{

         VARIANT writtenTime,genTime,logFile,eventCode,eventId,eventType,category;  
         BSTR strTimeWrittenProp = SysAllocString(L"TimeWritten");   
         hres = apObjArray[i]->Get(strTimeWrittenProp, 0, &writtenTime, 0, 0);   
         SysFreeString(strTimeWrittenProp); 

         //... Get other properties

         VariantClear( &writtenTime );
         //..clear variants before moving to next object in array
    enter code here
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to get the data from the query"
            << " Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        return WBEM_E_FAILED;       // Program has failed.
    }


}
```

Consider replacing all your get calls with this